# Internet functions appears disabled when game starts in the Atelier Plus games

Tags: ps-vita, networking, atelier-meruru-apprentice-of-arland, atelier-totori

On both Atelier Totori Plus and Atelier Mururu Plus, when the games boot, there's a system message stating that Internet/Network features were disabled.

The games itself does not have any online option therefore is there any real reason why they block the internet or a way of preventing them from disabling?
I mean, that stops PSN downloads and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unfortunate side effect of certain games...I think Uncharted Vita used to do it or something. As far as I can tell, it's simply the game disabling network features for...some reason, and there's nothing you can do to keep it from happening. I thought this was a bug or something that was fixed since I haven't seen it in months, but I guess devs can still do it.

It's possible the dev is "helping" by turning off network features to save your battery life, [this is apparently why Uncharted does it](http://www.examiner.com/article/why-uncharted-golden-abyss-disables-network-support-and-other-vita-quirks).

Comment: I think it's more because networking requires a bit of CPU power. Deactivating the networking capabilities means freeing that bit of CPU power for the game. It happens on the PS3 too, though it never notifies you about that. The PS4 is supposed to be immune from that predicament, since it apparently has a dedicated networking chip to ensure stable performance for both the game and the network connection.

Comment: @Nolonar that makes sense too--though if it's the case I'm surprised I don't see it more often. Maybe more of my games have network features than I realize though